# Adapt a macro to any range

Tags: excel, vba

I need to convert a list of IDs, first and last names, and others variables so that one unique ID appears per row, while the names and others variables populate the columns behind.
I found a vba code that allows me to convert a range of cells but it only converts the first two columns regardless of the range I select. Can you help me adapt it to any type of range.

Thanks for your help

I have this table:

| ID | Purchase | Cost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | mango | 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | lemon | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | sugar | 1 |

I want this table

| ID | Purchase1 | Purchase2 | Cost1 | Cost2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | mango | sugar | 2 | 1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | lemon |  | 3 |  |

```
Sub convert()
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, n As Long
Dim  x, z
Dim d As Object
Dim va As range
Dim rng As Range
Set d = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
d.CompareMode = vbTextCompare

va = Application.InputBox("Range?",,,Type:=8)
ReDim vb(1 To UBound(va, 1), 1 To 10000)

For i = 1 To UBound(va, 1)
    If Not d.Exists(va(i, 1)) Then
        d(va(i, 1)) = va(i, 2)
    Else
        d(va(i, 1)) = d(va(i, 1)) & "|" & va(i, 2)
    End If
Next

For Each x In d.keys
    k = k + 1
    vb(k, 1) = x
    j = 1
        For Each z In Split(d(x), "|")
            j = j + 1
            vb(k, j) = z
            If j > n Then n = j
        Next
Next

Range("D2").Resize(k, n) = vb
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you please explain what exactly the code does and what you expect it to do? Screenshots of data before the code and after would help, as well as a screenshot of the desired result.

Comment: I cannot add screenshot as I am a new member but I tried to explain what the macro was doing. It works but only for the first two columns, I would like to know what parameters I could change so that it works on more than two columns

Comment: Well the question is what dose it do **exactly**? What do you want to achieve with that code? *"convert a list of IDs"* actually tells us nothing about what it does. This is a way too broad to understand what you want your code to do. Give some example input and output data, if you cannot add screenshots.

Comment: As an example, I have in my database a customer with a single id who makes two purchases on two different days, so he is in the database on two lines with the same id but with in the purchase column two different purchases (sugar for the first purchase  and milk for the second) and with the costs in the third column. I want to have a table with one customer per row so the id, purchase1, purchase 2, cost1, cost2.

Comment: With example data I meant at least 2 to 5 data rows. Can you [edit] your question and put the examples there? You can [format them as table](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables) in your question. Show one example before using the code and another of what you expect as result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub Convert()
    ' Add reference "Microsoft Scripting Runtime"
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    Dim arr As Variant, arr2 As Variant, vb As Variant
    Dim str As String
    
    Dim dict As Scripting.Dictionary: Set dict = New Scripting.Dictionary
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    Dim va As Range: Set va = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Range?", Type:=8)
    
    For i = 1 To va.Rows.Count
        str = Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(Range(va(i, 2), va(i, va.Columns.Count)))), "#")
        If Not dict.Exists(va(i, 1).Value) Then
            dict.Add key:=va(i, 1).Value, Item:=str
        Else
            dict(va(i, 1).Value) = dict(va(i, 1).Value) & "|" & str
        End If
    Next
    
    ReDim vb(1 To dict.Count, 1 To 1 + (va.Columns.Count - 1) * va.Rows.Count)
    For k = 1 To dict.Count
        vb(k, 1) = dict.Keys(k - 1)
        arr = Split(dict.Items(k - 1), "|")
        For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
            arr2 = Split(arr(i), "#")
            For j = LBound(arr2) To UBound(arr2)
                vb(k, (va.Columns.Count - 1) * i + j + 2) = arr2(j)
            Next j
        Next i
     Next k
     Range("E2").Resize(dict.Count, 1 + (va.Columns.Count - 1) * va.Rows.Count) = vb
End Sub
```